# error in insert statment in jdbc

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to insert in dabase with following code

```
try{
String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
String url = "jdbc:odbc:ProductDSN";
Class.forName(driver);
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
System.out.println("Connection established");
System.out.println("clear point 1");
String sql  = "INSERT INTO product
(id,productName,category,price,availability,quantity,description)
VALUES('ID','name','catag','price','avail','quantity','discript')";
System.out.println("clear point 2");
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
System.out.println("clear point 3");
stmt.executeUpdate();
System.out.println("clear point 4");

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Save Successfully");

if (con != null)
  stmt.close();
con.close();
System.out.println("Connection Closed");
}
catch(SQLException sqle)
{
  System.err.println("Error is in save method");
  System.err.println(sqle);
}
```

and following are errors in compiling..

```
Connection established
clear poitn 1
clear point 2
clear point 3
Error is in save method
java.sql.SQLException: General error
```

Comment: all the datatypes of table are varchar only?

Comment: please provide a stacktrace

Comment: Please check the datatype of `id`,`price` and `quantity` whether they are integer or varchar

Comment: Can you please provide the datatypes of the columns.

Comment: Post your database table structure

Comment: @user3079252 see above all are asking the table structure, stack trace. Please provide the details if you want a solution

Comment: All data type in database file is Text.and in java file it is String type

Answer (score 2):

You are confused with the Prepared statement.

> The setter methods (setShort, setString, and so on) for setting IN
>   parameter values must specify types that are compatible with the
>   defined SQL type of the input parameter. For instance, if the IN
>   parameter has SQL type INTEGER, then the method setInt should be used.

So please try

```
String sql  = "INSERT INTO product
(id,productName,category,price,availability,quantity,description)
VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

and

```
stmt.setInt(1, value)// for Integer where 1 is the index
stmt.setString(2, value)// for string where 2 is the index
.....
```

and finally,

```
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

sql exception means error is int SQL query.
Check your sql query separately on the query browser.
Check whether you have given all attributes datatype as String..
you have given the values to insert as Strings..price,id etc..

check if it is in the same string format in the db also..
plz provide  the error display so i can help you more..

Answer (score 0):

Check out for Prepared Statement format & how to use it.